# Get the substring from the string by second vowels from behind the words

Tags: python, string

I want to do this:

```
a = "Describe"
```

I want to split `"Describe"` by the second vowel words from behind so it will be `"Descri"` and `"be"`.

Another example is `"Public"` which should split into `"Pu"` and `"blic"`.

I tried:

```
vowel = "AaIiUuEeOo"
consonant = "BbCcDdFfGgHhJjKkLlMmNnPpQqRrSsTtVvWwXxYyZz"
p = []
for char in words[::-1]:
    if char in consonant:
        p.append(char)
    elif char in vokal:
        p.append(char)
        break
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: To do it programmatically without using library - Phase 1 - Just traverse from the back and find the second vowel. Phase 2 - split and create two strings?

Comment: what is the exact error that you've got?

Comment: Just to let you know that `y` is also a vowel.

Comment: @codrelphi what?

Comment: Vowels are: a, e, i, o, u, y....

Comment: `w` and `y` are semi-vowels.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the regex `^(.*[AaIiUuEeOo])(?=.*[AaIiUuEeOo])(.+)$`. The idea is to capture everything up to a vowel that is followed by another vowel and, optionally some other characters which will be placed in the second capture group.

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = r"^(.*[AaIiUuEeOo])(?=.*[AaIiUuEeOo])(.+)$"
>>> re.match(pattern, "Describe").groups()
('Descri', 'be')
>>> re.match(pattern, "Public").groups()
('Pu', 'blic')
>>> re.match(pattern, "ibe").groups()
('i', 'be')
>>> re.match(pattern, "ie").groups()
('i', 'e')
```

If the string doesn't have at least two vowels, make sure to test for `None` before calling `groups()` on the result.

Another idea is to use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) which is clunkier but fun and generalizes well to any `n` or any set of characters (or iterables, for that matter--I stuck to strings here).

```
from itertools import groupby

def nth_from_rear(s, n=2, matches="aeiou"):
    def nth_counter(n=2, count=0):
        def cb(x):
            nonlocal count

            if x.lower() in matches:
                count += 1

            return count >= n

        return cb

    groups = groupby(s[::-1], key=nth_counter(n))
    return ["".join(x)[::-1] for _, x in groups][::-1]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    tests = [
        ["Public", 2],
        ["Describe", 2],
        ["ie", 2],
        ["ibbe", 2],
        ["Describe", 0],
        ["Describing", 1],
        ["Describe", 3],
        ["ababbaba", 4],
    ]

    for s, n in tests:
        print(s.rjust(10), n, nth_from_rear(s, n))
```

Output:

```
    Public 2 ['Pu', 'blic']
  Describe 2 ['Descri', 'be']
        ie 2 ['i', 'e']
      ibbe 2 ['i', 'bbe']
  Describe 0 ['Describe']
Describing 1 ['Describi', 'ng']
  Describe 3 ['De', 'scribe']
  ababbaba 4 ['a', 'babbaba']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use string slicing:

```
def s_split(s):
   l = [i for i in range(len(s)) if s[i].lower() in 'aeiou']
   return [s[:l[len(l) > 2]+1], s[l[len(l) > 2]+1:]]
```

Output:

```
['Pu', 'blic']
['Descri', 'be']
['i', 'e']
['i', 'bbe']
['Descri', 'be']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want without using any libraries:

```
vowel = "AaIiUuEeOo"
consonant = "BbCcDdFfGgHhJjKkLlMmNnPpQqRrSsTtVvWwXxYyZz"
p = []
words = 'Public'
vowelCount = 0
secondPart = ''
firstPart = ''
for index, char in enumerate(words[::-1]):
    if char in vowel:
      vowelCount += 1
      if vowelCount == 2:
        firstPart = words[:-index]
        break
    secondPart += char
secondPart = secondPart[::-1]
print(firstPart, secondPart)
```

Output:

```
Pu blic
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution. It first iterates the word in reverse to find the *nth* last letter that is a vowel, and returns it's index. Then you can simply return a tuple of the word split at the *nth* vowels index. If no *nth* vowel is found, `None` is returned and the full word is just returned.

```
def get_nth_last_vowel(items, n):
    vowels = {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u"}

    count = 0
    for i in reversed(range(len(items))):

        if items[i].lower() in vowels:
            count += 1

            if count == n:
                return i

def split_nth_last_vowel(word, n):
    idx = get_nth_last_vowel(word, n)

    return word[: idx + 1], word[idx + 1 :] if idx != None else word
```

**Output:**

```
>>> split_nth_last_vowel("Public", 2)
('Pu', 'blic')
>>> split_nth_last_vowel("Describe", 2)
('Descri', 'be')
>>> split_nth_last_vowel("ibe", 2)      
('i', 'be')
>>> split_nth_last_vowel("ie", 2)  
('i', 'e')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to put my two cents in, you could use an iterator function:

```
strings = ["Public", "Describe", "ie", "ababbaba"]

def split_by_vowel(string):

    # variables
    vowels, cnt, buffer = ["aeiouAEIOU", 0, ""]
    it = iter(string)
    parts = list()

    while True:
        try:
            char = next(it)
            buffer += char
            if char in vowels:
                cnt += 1
                parts.append(buffer)
                buffer = ""
        except StopIteration:
            if buffer:
                parts.append(buffer)
            break

    return ["".join(part for part in parts[0:cnt-1]), "".join(parts[cnt-1:])]


for string in strings:
    print(split_by_vowel(string))
```

This yields

```
['Pu', 'blic']
['Descri', 'be']
['i', 'e']
['ababba', 'ba']
```